# Run thread on button press

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, jbutton

I have a GUI with the following button. When it is pressed it should run a new thread (I have a class which implements Runnable). However, when I do that, the GUI freezes. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it??

```
        //button
        addKitchenStaff.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //create object of a class which implements runnable
                KitchenStaff kitchenStaff = new KitchenStaff(allDishes, ingredientsModel, dishesModel,communication.getBap());
                //arraylist of all such objects
                allKitchenStaff.add(kitchenStaff);

                Thread thread = new Thread(kitchenStaff);
                thread.run();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run a thread, you should call `start()` method.

try `thread.start()` instead of `thread.run()`

Answer (score 2):

`run()` works on the calling `Thread`. Use `start()` instead